# Generating campaign report with each subcriber unique interaction

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-report-type

I'm trying to create campaign report where it shows each subscriber interaction. by default SFMC, generate report for by aggregating email name with its tracking result. Without mentioning each subscriber engagement. The only way to do that is customized report by creating DE. Anyone can suggest how.

Comment: Could you explain the data you want in this report, please? Maybe add a screenshot of the data you need in something like Sheets or Excel.

Comment: Let's assume in the campaign, I have target DE with 10 subscribers and two emails. For the report what I want is showing each subscriber open, click, click url for each email. into one report

Comment: Ah... The inclusion of Campaign means this is more than a few pieces of SQL because the Campaign Asset metadata isn't exposed in any Data View. You'd need to first hit the REST API to retrieve CampaignAssets and place Campaign emails in a Data Extension and then use this data together with Sent, Open and Click Data Views for your final report. It'd take a few hours to put together